# What Does 'Exit' Mean?

Tags: die2nite

I've noticed a small square button hiding in the top right corner of my [Die2Nite](http://www.die2nite.com/) screen.  It simply bears a red **X** and the ominous intonation, **"EXIT"**

I fear greatly what would transpire if ever I clicked upon it.

---

[image: Tremble, mortal survivor.]

---

What severe fate awaits all ye who depress the button (What does it do)?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not allow you to exit your current existence, which would come in handy right about now...

Comment: Having a tag called "buttons" seems unnecessary.  Is there a reason you felt you needed to add it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you hover over it, you can see that the URL is: `http://www.die2nite.com/#user/logout?sk=#####`

Therefore, even though I've never pushed that creepy button, I assume that it logs you out.

Answer (score 17):

Your session is eaten by Cthulhu.

[image]

Comment: Again?? *sigh* AdAware just isn't up to dealing with the Old Gods.

Comment: @StuartPegg: ??

Comment: @badp: Sorry, "Great Old Ones". Near miss.

Comment: @Stuart: Yeah, I'm confused about the AdAware bit :) If the image is offensive to you, I can remove it.

Comment: @badp: Haha! No, not more offensive than expected. AdAware is a tool to stop programs doing silly or malicious things (possibly like clearing your session without your permission).

Comment: @Stuart Haha. No, by that I meant "invalidating your session cookie". Which means ending your browsing session with the site. Which means logging you out. :)

Answer (score 10):

It logs you out of the game and the website.